# How do I properly delete nodes of linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I feel as if I am not actually deleting the node and freeing up memory. I think I am just moving pointers around so when I print the linked list the list doesn't print the element I deleted. So my question is am I actually deleting the node or am I just simply rearranging the pointers so it looks like I am deleting the nodes(Essentially just breaking the links but not deleting the node)? Thank you for any help.

```
void SLL::deleteNode(int target){
Node *current = new Node;
Node *previous = new Node;

for (current = front->next, previous = front; current != NULL; current = current->next, previous=previous->next){
    if (previous->data == target && previous == front){
        front = previous->next;
        delete[] previous;
        return;
    //This if statement deletes the element if its the front
    }

    else {

        if (previous->data == target && previous->next == NULL){
            previous = NULL;
            delete[] current;
            return;
        //This if statement deletes the node if it is the back
        }


        else if (current->data==target)
        {
            previous->next = current->next;
            delete[] current;
            return;
        //This if statement deletes a node if it is in the middle
        }
    }
    }

    delete[] current;
    delete[] previous;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the array delete (`delete []`) version when you declare `current` and `previous` as a single instance?

Comment: Starting your enumeration algorithm with `front->next` is concerning. *Please* tell us you're not using a pre-allocated "head" node that doesn't actually contain data. It isn't needed. And unless you allocated your node with `new Node[n]`, you're using the wrong `delete` operator.

Comment: I dont know. I tried this it worked. Please answer the question.

Comment: Don't know *what* ? Whether your front pointer is a sentinel node? Whether your nodes are allocated with vector-`new` ? You wrote the code, right? And btw,the two nodes you're allocating at the head of this function are immediately being leaked, so I can assure you in the end there is zero memory being recouped, whether you deleted a target node or not.

Comment: You `delete[]` a null vector in your second block, but I don't think that control can ever enter that block, so I guess it's moot.

Comment: I used new to create new nodes then I used previous and current to allow me to do the delete in the middle. It properly traverses my linked list and then displays the data as if they were removed. I dont know anything about memory leaks really and thats why I asked the question I asked isnt it? So I could learn how to properly delete nodes not just break the links.

Comment: It would help if you answered the two open questions in these comments: do you use a sentinel node, and is this a linked list of `Node`, or a linked list of `Node[]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Node *current  = new Node;
Node *previous = new Node;
```

This code causes memory leaks - you are never deleting this memory. You can declare pointers without memory allocation:

```
Node *current  = nullptr;
Node *previous = nullptr;
```

`delete` will delete the memory of the pointer so you will actually delete Nodes. 
But using [delete[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/) for the `Node*` **is incorrect**, it should be used only for arrays - the memory allocated with `new[]`. Improper use leads to undefined behaviour.
So, to properly delete nodes delete them with operator **delete**.

Use memory leaks detection tools to know are there memory leaks in you program.

The code to delete a list element: say, we have pHead which points to the head of the list
(but it would give you much more if you write such things yourself):

```
Node* pCur  = pHead;
Node* pPrev = pCur;

while (pCur && pCur->data != target) {
    pPrev = pCur;
    pCur  = pCur->next;
}

if (pCur==nullptr)  // not found
   return NOT_FOUND;

if (pCur == pHead) {   // first element matches
    pHead = pCur->next;
} else {
    pPrev->next = pCur->next;
}

// pCur now is excluded from the list

delete pCur;     // deallocate its memory
```

---

**Alternative Using Pointer To Pointer** (Community Addition)

The above can take on new light when you use the actual pointers *in* the list to perform the enumeration. The following starts with `pp` being assigned *the address* of the head pointer (not the node it points to; the actual pointer itself). We walk the list until `pp` hold the address of a pointer that is pointing to a node with the target to delete (could be the head pointer, could be a `next` pointer in some node, makes no difference). The pointer being addressed is set to its own node's `next` value, then the target node is removed.

This really should be watched in a debugger to see how it works, but the algorithm is remarkably simple given what is really going on:

```
Node **pp = &pHead;
while (*pp && (*pp)->data != target)
    pp = &(*pp)->next;

if (*pp)
{
    Node *victim = *pp;
    *pp = victim->next;
    delete victim;
}
```

Thats *all* of it. And you get head-node removal without having to special case it for free. Hope this helps as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will no longer use new for them from this point on. Although my question still remains, how do I delete my target node? I know you touched on it but can you explain a little more perhaps.

Comment: @user3291106 - I provide a sample code. But it would be much more useful for you to write it yourself. Try now double-linked list and, say, search from end.

Comment: @Alex How does this finish when `pHead` points to the node that will be deleted? Follow: The while-loop will be skipped and do nothing. `pHead->next` will effectively be assigned to itself because `pPrev`, `pCur`, and `pHead` all point to the same node. The head node will then be destroyed with `delete pCur;`,  thereby orphaning the entire remainder of the list and leaving all three pointers holding an invalid, indeterminate address. In a word, *ouch*.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for the correction! Fixed it. Although I would prefer that _user3291106_ tell me about it :)

I need not to hurry with code posts, agree.

Comment: @Alex no problem. have a gander at the addendum. Not sure if you've ever seen it before, but it deserves a look. And +1 for sticking with the answer.