# Delete elements conditionally in a Singly Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem in a function that deletes an element in a singly linked list. The element needs to be deleted conditionnaly with the function ShouldDelete().

I haven't found a similar request in C++ in the forums so any help would be appreciated. It seems that the following code does not work 100% of the time.

```
void SinglyLinkedList::DeleteObjects(Node *pStartPtr)
{
    Node *pPtr = pStartPtr;
    Node *temp;
    while(pPtr != nullptr)
    {
        temp = pPtr->next;
        if (pPtr->ShouldDelete())
        {
            delete pPtr;
            pPtr = temp;
            if(temp != nullptr)
            {
               pPtr->next = temp->next;
            }
        }
        pPtr = temp;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts ?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW.: Im always passing the head of the list as an argument.

Comment: `pPtr->next = temp->next;` this won't do anything since `pPtr = temp;` And then to delete any node you need a pointer to previous node which you don't have. Maybe you want to delete `temp` as `pPtr` can serve as the previous pointer

Comment: You can't delete the head pointer with this code unless you allow for the head pointer to change. if this was `c++` you could change `void SinglyLinkedList::DeleteObjects(Node* pStartPtr)` to `void SinglyLinkedList::DeleteObjects(Node* & pStartPtr)` to fix this. There would be different methods for `c`.

Comment: With :: and delete , C tag can probably be removed

Comment: *BTW.: Im always passing the head of the list as an argument.* this raises the question "Why?" Is the list head not a member of `SinglyLinkedList`? If not, new question: "Why not?"

Comment: Sidenote: deleting nodes from singly linked lists is almost laughably easy when you use a pointer to a pointer to a `Node` (`Node **`) and point it to the the address of the `next` pointer. This `Node**` provides an updatable link to the last `Node` and to the `Node` you're investigating. [Great example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301).

Answer (score 0):

As a general C++ advice, I would use std::list instead of a DIY list implementation, but since I wrote quite some list logic myself in the old C-days, I'll give it a go.

There are 2 essential problems with your code.

First of all, whenever removing an element from a single-linked list, you should set the next pointer of the previous element to the next of the deleted one.  You can do something like this:

```
Node *previousNode = …;
while(pPtr != nullptr)
   {
   Node *nextNode = pPtr->next;
   if (pPtr->ShouldDelete())
      {
      delete pPtr;
      previousNode->next = nextNode;
      }
   else
      {
      previousNode = pPtr;
      }
   pPtr = nextNode;
   }
```

Notice that no specific if-tests within the for-loop on `nullptr` are needed.   You should tell the previous node that it now points to the next of the deleted one.  If there is no next one, the `previous->next` will just point to a nullptr, indicating the end of the list.

The second problem is that you don't have any clear 'start of the list'.  In my example code above, it becomes quite hard to indicate what the `previousNode` is.  Is it a `nullptr`?  But what if we remove the first element?

You could easily add logic here to indicate keep track of the first element, initialize `previousNode` to nullptr, and if the first is deleted, just don't set `previousNode->next' and keep previousNode equal to`nullptr` in that case, but what about the caller?  How can the caller know that the first element has been deleted and the list now starts later.

My preferred solution is to have a separate `List` struct/class, and keep the start of the list (the first Node) as a member in the `List` struct/class.  Instead of passing the startNode to the function, you should pass the `List` instance.
The code in the while-loop now becomes a bit longer, since you need to adapt `previousNode->next=nextNode` to this:

```
if (previousNode)
   previousNode->next = nextNode;
else
   list->firstNode = nextNode;
```

If you don't want to introduce a new `List` struct/class, you could also return the new `firstNode` as return value from your function, like this:

```
if (previousNode)
   previousNode->next = nextNode;
else
   startNode  = nextNode;
…
return startNode;
```

Notice that this second approach only works if the caller if the function is also the one maintaining the list, and there are no other places pointing to the startNode.
In any case, if multithreading is involved, you probably want a decent `List` class with a kind of `mutex` (ideally `std::list` decorated with a `mutex`).