# Removing the last node, and updating the tail to the last node

Tags: c++

I want to remove the last node in my linked list, but it seems like I'm doing something wrong, since no element gets deleted.

```
void deleteTail(){
    node *temp = head;
    int iterator = 1;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Nothing to be deleted."<<endl;
    }
    else if (head == tail)
    {
        temp = head;
        delete(temp);
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        tail = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        delete(temp);
    }
}
```

If the linked list was 
       1->2->3->4->5->NULL
I want it to turn into
       1->2->3->4->NULL.
What am I doing wrong in my code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user4581301 I'm sorry for the confusion caused, I'm actually trying to delete the last node, updated the post!

Comment: Thanks. This makes much more sense. You'll need to iterate through the list until you find the link  who's `next` is `tail`. Set its `next` to `NULL` to cut off `tail`. Delete `tail` and set `tail` to point at the link you found.

Comment: @user4581301 am I not doing that in the last else block?

Comment: Close, but not quite. After `while(temp->next != NULL)`, you know that `temp->next == NULL`, so you've lost the previous node and have the tail node. And because `temp->next == NULL`, `temp = temp->next;` sets `temp` to `NULL`, so `delete(temp);` is effectively `delete(NULL);`. Nothing is done. You want `while(temp->next != tail)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
}

tail = temp;
delete temp->next;
temp->next = NULL;
```

The problem was at the end of the loop, `temp` is pointing at the last element. After that, you are setting `temp` to `temp->next`, or in other words to `NULL`. After that you are calling `delete` over `NULL` which does nothing.

Edit: Of course, this goes into the last `else` block.

Comment: Doesn't condition of the while loop,  while(temp->next !=NULL), bring my temp node to the node before the last one?

Comment: @BlinQipa No, `temp->next != NULL` brings it to the last element, not the one before. `temp->next == NULL` is true only for the last element. The condition `temp->next->next != NULL` stops the loop at the node before the last one because if `temp` points at the element before the last one, then `temp->next` points at the last one and `temp->next->next` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This removes the second to last node since this was the original question.

You'll need to keep track of the previous nodes. When you remove the node prior to the last one (second to last node) then the tail remains the same but you have to point the node prior to the second-to-last node to the tail:

```
while (temp->next != NULL) {
    if ((temp->next->next != NULL) &&        
        (temp->next->next->next == NULL)) {  // the second node after temp is tail
        delete temp->next;                   // delete second-to-last node
        temp->next = tail;       // two nodes back set to tail
        break;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(temp->next != NULL){
    temp = temp -> next;
}
tail = temp;
temp = temp->next;
delete(temp);
```

is really close, but `while(temp->next != NULL)` is only false at the end of the linked list. This means the code has iterated to the last node, assigned `tail` to itself and deleted the null pointer terminating the linked list.

Instead use

```
while(temp->next != tail){
    temp = temp -> next;
}
tail = temp;
temp = temp->next;
delete(temp);
tail->next = NULL;
```

This will stop on the node that points to `tail`, the second last item in the list, assign the second last as the new `tail`, `delete` the old `tail`, and terminate the new `tail` with a `NULL`

There is an excellent [general case using a pointer to a pointer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) that simplifies the code greatly.