# segmentation fault in an sorted linked list program for Homework

Tags: c++, qt-creator, segmentation-fault

i know there are already so many question and answer about this error. But with many Topic i still can not find the Problem in my Program. I must write a sorted Linked List, but i tried and tried and got the Error when i´m trying to get the next Node. I am pretty new to C++ so can u guys please help me out . And sorry for my bad English.

Booking.h

```
class Booking { 
public: 
Booking() : data{nullptr},nextNode{nullptr}, prevNode{nullptr} 
{}
Booking(Booking* d) :data{d}, nextNode{nullptr}, prevNode{nullptr} {} 

Booking* getNextNode() const { 

return nextNode; // where the SIGSEGV happened, i checked by debugger

 } 
private:
 Booking* nextNode;
 Booking* prevNode; 
 Booking* data;
 }
```

SortedLinkedList.h

```
 template<typename T> 

 class SortedLinkedList { 

 public: 

 SortedLinkedList() {
 root = NULL; 
 end = new T; 
 cursor = end;
 size = 0; 
}

 void insertNode(T* data)
{ 
 T* node = new T(data); 
 cursor = root;

 while(cursor->getNextNode()){ // here it go to getNextNode


} 

} 
private: 
T* root; 
T* cursor; 
T* end; }
```

TravelAgency.h

```
 class TravelAgency{
 public: 
 void readFile();
 private: 
 SortedLinkedList<Booking> allBookings ;
 }
```

TravelAgency.cpp

```
 void TravelAgency::readFile(){

 allBookings.insertNode(flight); // flight is an obj of an derived class 
}
```

Comment: The `...` ellipses make the problem a lot harder to diagnose because the code is incomplete. Please post a [mcve] that can be easily run to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The program does not reach these ... so i write nothing in it. The Fault happened right when i tried to use the get function.

Comment: where _flight_ is coming from ? the little part of the code you give supposes _flight_ is a new instance each time, is it true ? How is the sort done, you say the erro occurs during the sort but you do not show how you do

Comment: "_The Fault happened right when i tried to use the get function._" there is no `get()` function in the code !

Comment: Then remove these parts completely from the program. If I need to go through your program line by line adjusting the source code to make it run, it's a lot harder to verify that my program == your program and is generally going to make people less likely to answer your question.

Comment: In the while loop , the List should be sorted. The Error just occurred before i sort the list.

Comment: I wrote a comment next to where the error occurred

Comment: @TrungHieuLe look at the answer of _Jeffrey_

Comment: Ggorlen ok i will try to remove it now

Comment: @TrungHieuLe how is it possible you edited your question like that ? Ggorlen asked you to replace the "..." by the original code, not to just remove the "..." like if there is no code. Do you really think we have magic crystal balls allowing us to guess all you hide ?

Comment: Recommendation: Separate `Booking` from the linked list node. A class should represent one and only one thing, and here you have a class representing two things. This has a tendency to make your code less manageable over the long run as well as rendering it difficult to reuse. Once you have separated the responsibilities, you can hide the nodes from sight and get a much more robust linked list.

Comment: @bruno , it just simple that the program does not reached these.... part. The List was empty, the first time insertNode() being called then the fault occurred.

Comment: @user4581301 i did do have the node.h. But after i get this Error then i tried to combine these Booking and Node  :) seemed worser

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor, you set *root* to Null.

Then in insertNode, you do:

```
cursor = root;
while(cursor->getNextNode())
```

You need to allocate a root node, or deal with it being Null.

Comment: In this case, my cursor is null ,however is it still a Booking ?  In constructor of Booking i had the nextNode = nullptr, so when i use cursor->getNextNode() , should it be nullptr and the While-loop still run ?

Comment: @TrungHieuLe this is a place where pointers to pointers can be very helpful. There is no difference other than name between `root` and any `nextNode`, and with a pointer to either `root` or `nextNode` you can abstract that difference away. This save you from writing a lot of code. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) that removes an item from a list using pointer-to-pointer. You can adapt the logic to insert.