# Seg Fault: Linked List Node Insertion Function [C++]

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have created a function called 'Insert' for inserting a new node in a Linked List. It takes the value and the head node for insertion.
When I manually add the nodes myself, the program runs as expected however 
I get a segmentation fault when I use the function for adding a node.

I am able to make the function work with a couple of little tweaks but there's another catch, I lose the head node's property of just being a pointer, it now contains some garbage data in it which gets printed when I print the LinkedList.

The tweak I perform is:

```
Change Line 26 to: A->next = NULL;
Change Line 17 to: while(temp->next != NULL)
```

The 'segmentation fault' occurs at Line 20 (when the tweak is not done):

```
Line 20 ----->  temp->next = addTo;
```

I've already tried passing the arguments by reference, using global variables for the head node and checking the logic of the function.
The logic works for manually adding a node.

I have attached the complete code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode {
int data;
ListNode *next;
};

void Insert(int x , ListNode* head)
{
    ListNode* addTo = new ListNode();
    addTo->data = x;
    addTo->next = NULL;

    ListNode* temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = addTo;
}

int main()
{
    ListNode* A;
    A = NULL;

    //Inserting A Node Manually
    // ListNode* first = new ListNode();
    // first->data = 9;
    // first->next = NULL;
    // while(A != NULL)
    // A = A->next;
    //     A = first;

    //Inserting using Insert function.
   Insert(2,A);Insert(3,A);Insert(6,A);Insert(7,A);

    //Printing
    ListNode* temp = A;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the node to be added to the list as the logic seems to be correct, however I am getting a segmentation fault.

Any help/insight into this would help a lot.

Thank You.

Comment: You issue may stem from the non-standard header file `bits/stdc++.h`.  Use standard headers not compiler specific.

Comment: Getting myself back on topic, one of the best ways to debug linked lists is by drawing pictures. Draw the list. Then step by step perform all of the operations in the function you wish to debug on the list. When you find yourself drawing something silly, you just found a bug.

Comment: With `ListNode* A` you have a pointer, but without reserved memory for its contents. So, `A=NULL` should be `A= new ListNode()`

Comment: So, what are the results of your debugging session?

Comment: Easy fix: your loop iterates until `temp` is `NULL`. Then, you try to access the the `next` pointer in that location. You should iterate until `temp->next` is `NULL`, since that will be the tail of the list.

Comment: Debugging: I get a segmentation fault at Line 20 : temp->next = addTo;

Comment: Great start. The next thing to do is use the debugger to  display all of the variables involved in that line. If you find something nasty like `temp` being null, work your way back through the code to see why it is null.

Comment: @anonmess close, but think on what happens if `temp` starts null.

Comment: @user4581301 ah good point, I always forget about that in a situation like this, since I always include a check first to see if `head` is `NULL`.

Comment: @anonmess I tried that fix and I don't get the Seg fault anymore and now I understand why, but I still have the head node printed with some value.

Comment: Something that will help later is knowing that you can pass an object through a pointer to be able to change the object, but sometimes you need to change the pointer itself and have to pass a pointer (or a reference) to the pointer.

Comment: @user4581301, Yes I got temp with a value 0x0 which I guess is NULL.

Comment: Yes 0x0 is NULL. @anonmess explained how to fix this problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks. Can you tell me more about what you're hinting at? Also, I fixed the seg fault with all of your help, but the head node's data is still getting printed.

Comment: Your code does not allow replacing head.

Comment: I want the head to be just a pointer to the node where I want to start storing the data from. I don't want any data in head node. I am not sure if I'm making complete sense here but isn't it how the abstract data structure is?

Comment: change `void Insert(int x , ListNode* head)` to `void Insert(int x , ListNode*& head)` and head can be changed.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. I got the approach now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem 1:

```
while(temp != NULL)
temp = temp->next;

temp->next = addTo;
```

Guarantees that `temp` will be `NULL` when `while(temp != NULL)` exits. that means there is no `temp` to get the `next` from.

Rather than solve this here, I'm going to move on to problem 2 and kill two birds with one stone.

## Problem 2:

```
void Insert(int x , ListNode* head)
```

leaves you with no way to update the caller if `head` is changed in the `Insert` function. You can change the object pointed at by `head`, but `head` itself is just a copy of an address. If you change this copy to point at another address, the caller does not know.

This means every time you call `Insert(<number>, A);`, `A` will always be `NULL`.

## Solution:

Pass `head` into `Insert` by reference so that it can be updated.

```
void Insert(int x , ListNode*& head)
                             ^ reference to pointer
```

`head`'s job is to point at the first item in the list. This makes means it does the same thing as any `next` pointer: It points at  the next item. The only difference is the name. We can get rid of this difference by adding an extra indirection, a pointer to `head`.

```
ListNode ** temp = &head;
```

Note that we cannot use a reference (`ListNode *& temp`) here because once you initialize a reference to refer to an object, it cannot be changed to refer to a different object. A pointer you can change, allowing us to iterate through the list and always point `temp` at the next `next`.

Now `head` or any `next` is simply `temp`. This makes `head` exactly the same as every other `next` variable and no special cases are required.

```
void Insert(int x , ListNode*& head)   
{
    ListNode* addTo = new ListNode(); 
    addTo->data = x;
    addTo->next = NULL; // consider making a smarter ListNode constructor that makes 
                        // it impossible to forget to set next.

    ListNode ** temp = &head; // we can now manipulate the address in head through temp
                  
    while(*temp != NULL) // note the dereference to get the pointed at pointer
                         // temp won't be null, but it could be pointing at a pointer 
                         // that is null, and that is the end of the list
    { // I always use the optional braces. They prevent confusion.
        temp = &(*temp)->next; //get pointer to the next next pointer
                               // we can now manipulate it exactly the same as head. 
    }
    // we exit the loop with a pointer to the next pointer that we wish to point at 
    // the new list item regardless of whether it's head or the next of some later
    // link in the list
    *temp = addTo; // update the pointed at pointer with the new Node.
}
```

The Community Addition the first answer of [How do I properly delete nodes of linked list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121257/how-do-i-properly-delete-nodes-of-linked-list-in-c) demonstrates how to use the same pointer-to-pointer trick to make removing nodes easy.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Viktor If that answer your question, you could accept the answer by ticking the right mark on it.