# How to sort structure

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct

I have structure in C which looks like:

```
typedef struct node {
  int id;
  int salary;
  struct node *next;
  char name[30];
  char phone[10];
  char position[30];
} List;
```

I also have two variables List type and I want to sort the structures by id (the largest id will be last).
My idea how to resolve this:

1. Do **pointer point on *head (*head = pointer on first member of List).
2. Check if **pointer.id larger then **pointer.next.id
   If yes -> **pointer.next will point on *pointer.next.next
   **pointer.next.next will point on &pointer

Here is code of solving this problem (I will do "cosmetics" of code and bubble sort algorithm after. Firstable just want to build code which will be work):

```
void sort(List head) {
  int length = getListLength(head);
  List **currentNode = &head;

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    **currentNode = &head;
    for(int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if(currentNode->id > currentNode->next->id) {
        currentNode->next = currentNode->next->next;
        currentNode->next->next = &currentNode;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is errors:

```
         ^             ~~~~~
list.c:92:19: error: assigning to 'List' (aka 'struct node') from incompatible type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *'); remove &
    **currentNode = &head;
                  ^ ~~~~~
list.c:94:21: error: member reference base type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union
      if(currentNode->id > currentNode->next->id) {
         ~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~
list.c:94:39: error: member reference base type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union
      if(currentNode->id > currentNode->next->id) {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
list.c:95:20: error: member reference base type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union
        currentNode->next = currentNode->next->next;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
list.c:95:40: error: member reference base type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union
        currentNode->next = currentNode->next->next;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
list.c:96:20: error: member reference base type 'List *' (aka 'struct node *') is not a structure or union
        currentNode->next->next = &currentNode;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
```

Please give me some way to fix this (without solving the problem. Just want to know what is wrong in my code and then fix it by myself).

Main function:

```
int main() {
  List *head = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
  if(head == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  head -> id = 332513075;
  head -> salary = 1000;
  strcpy(head -> name, "Name Lastname");
  strcpy(head -> phone, "0587885238");
  strcpy(head -> position, "cleaner");

  head -> next = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));

  head -> next->id = 2;
  head -> next->salary = 2000;
  strcpy(head -> next -> name, "Another name");
  strcpy(head -> next -> phone, "1234567890");
  strcpy(head -> next -> position, "CEO");
  head -> next -> next = NULL;

  sort(*head);
  print_list(*head);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why double pointer ? **currentNode = &head

Comment: The immediate fix is `List *currentNode = &head;` but I can see lots of reasons why this code is not going to work.

Comment: @rootkonda Because head is pointer on first structure.

Comment: @BalmainVuitton `head` in not a pointer in the code you've posted.

Comment: @BalmainVuitton Now you've posted more code I'll clarify that. `head` is a pointer in the main function, but it is not a pointer in the `sort` function.

Comment: @john edited the post with main function which contains head as pointer.

Comment: @BalmainVuitton I can see that, why don't you pass head as a pointer to the `sort` and `printList` functions? That's the normal thing to do.

Comment: IMHO, a better sort method is to move the elements of the list into a new list, using an *insert sort*, only changing the links (no need to copy the nodes).

Comment: @rootkonda believe it or not using a pointer-to-pointer to a node can make the book-keeping when altering a singly linked list far, far easier to handle. Asker might be using it wrong here, but it is a good strategy. Here's an example of this trick in action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301 See how much simpler the pointer-to-pointer version in the community addition is?

Comment: @user4581301. I agree. Any feature or concept when used in appropriate situation yields efficient and simpler answer. My comments are specific in this context. When I saw it first time in the given example, it just hit me that something might be wrong here. Hence I asked my question.

Comment: Meanwhile I just did bubble sort which swaps values but not pointers. After all semester projects I will seat and try understand better all about pointers, linked lists etc and I'll try to realise the sort function. Thx for all

Answer (score 1):

- The first error: `head` is a `List`, so `&head` would be a `List*`; but you are trying to assign it to a `List**`.
- The others stem from treating `currentNode` as if it were a `List*`.

So declaring `currentNode` as a `List*` would solve the listed errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need following modifications:

1. pass address of head as I suppose sort function needs to update head after sorting and pass head to print_list:
   sort(&head);
   print_list(head);
2. sort algorithm seems incorrect. I am not sharing modifications in algorithm but sharing modifications to remove error and updating head pointer.:

   void sort(List **head)
   {
   int length = getListLength(*head);
   List *currentNode = *head;
   // kindly implement Algo here using currentNode as pointer to list
   *head = ...  ;  // update head pointer
   }