# Trying to fix error in a program for removing duplicates in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am executing a program for removing duplicates from an unsorted linked list using two loops.

The program includes two `structs` for defining `Node` and `newNode`. Also, it includes two user-defined functions `removeDuplicates` for removing duplicates of linked-list and `printList` for printing the list.

```
struct Node {
       int data;
       struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *newNode(int data) {
       Node *temp = new Node;
       temp->data = data;
       temp->next = NULL;

       return temp;
};

/* Function to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list */
void removeDuplicates(struct Node *start) {
     struct Node *ptr1, *ptr2, *dup;
     ptr1 = start;

     while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next != NULL) {
           ptr2 = ptr1;

           while (ptr2->next != NULL) {
                 if (ptr1->data == ptr2->next->data) {
                    dup = ptr2->next;
                    ptr2->next = ptr2->next->next;
                    delete (dup);
                 } else
                    ptr2 = ptr2->next;

                 ptr1 = ptr1->next;
           }
     }
}

void printList(struct Node *node) {
     while (node != NULL) {
           printf("%d  ", node->data);
           node = node->next;
     }

     printf("\n");
}
```

I ran a couple of test cases,

**case 1** Input : 12->11->12->21->41->43->21

```
   Output(from the program) : 12->11->12->21->41->43->21
       Required Output : 12->11->21->41->43
```

```
int main() {
    struct Node *start = newNode(12);
    start->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next = newNode(12);
    start->next->next->next = newNode(21);
    start->next->next->next->next = newNode(41);
    start->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(43);
    start->next->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(21);

    printf("Linked List before removing duplicates");
    printList(start);

    removeDuplicates(start);

    printf("Linked List after removing duplicates");
    printList(start);
}
```

**case 2** Input : 10->12->11->11->12->11->10

```
       Output : 10->12->11
```

```
int main() {
    struct Node *start = newNode(10);
    start->next = newNode(12);
    start->next->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next->next = newNode(12);
    start->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(11);
    start->next->next->next->next->next->next = newNode(10);

    printf("Linked List before removing duplicates");
    printList(start);

    removeDuplicates(start);

    printf("Linked List after removing duplicates");
    printList(start);
}
```

The program works for one test case and not other case. What am I missing in the code?

Comment: Have you tried running your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables? If not, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Don't do `delete(dup);` You are not doing `new` anywhere. Also, make a [mre]

Comment: You're still missing the definition of  `printList`

Comment: Shouldn't the line `ptr1 = ptr1->next;` be at the end of the outer loop? Currently, it is at the end of the inner loop.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, It worked. Thanks for suggesting the debugging links.

Comment: Warning: It looks like someone may be teaching you C and telling you it is C++. Do not be fooled. [Upgrade your reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so that you can be aware of the differences.

Comment: If you make a slightly smarter `newNode`, `Node *newNode(int data, Node * next){ Node *temp = new Node; temp->data = data; temp->next = next; return temp; }` the huge mass of `start->next->next->next->next->next->next`s can be reduced to something like `start = newNode(1, newNode(2, newNode(3, NULL)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
while ((ptr1 != NULL) && (ptr1->next != NULL))
{
        ptr2 = ptr1;
        while (ptr2->next != NULL)
        {
            // delete if duplicate
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
}
```

You are moving `ptr1` inside the loop that removes the duplicates, but it needs to be moved once per node in the linked-list:

```
while ((ptr1 != NULL) && (ptr1->next != NULL))
{
        ptr2 = ptr1;
        while (ptr2->next != NULL)
        {
            // delete if duplicate
        }
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;  // move ptr1 here
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/15dzM5).

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Function to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list*/
void removeDuplicates(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *ptr1 = start;

    while (ptr1) {
   
        struct Node *ptr2     = ptr1->next;
        struct Node *ptr2prev = ptr1;

        while (ptr2) {

            if (ptr1->data == ptr2->data) {
                
                struct Node *tmp = ptr2;

                ptr2prev->next   = ptr2->next;
                ptr2             = ptr2->next;
                
                delete tmp;
                continue;
            }  

            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            ptr2prev = ptr2prev->next;
        }  

        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Note: you can greatly reduce the amount of book-keeping required with a pointer-to-pointer. See the Community Addition [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. The below code will work.

```
void removeDuplicates(struct Node *start)
{
    struct Node *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
    ptr1 = start;
    while ((ptr1 != NULL) )
    {
        ptr2 = ptr1->next;
        ptr3=ptr1; //used inside the next while loop
        while (ptr2 != NULL)
        {
            if ((ptr1->data) == (ptr2->data))
            {
                ptr3->next = ptr2->next;
                delete (ptr2);
                ptr2 = ptr3->next
            }
            else
            {
                ptr3 = ptr2; //prev of next ptr2
                ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            }
        }
        ptr1=ptr1->next;
    }
}
```

You are modifying the variable ptr1 inside the first while loop. Since you have to compare the first element with all the remaining elements of the linked list, you should only change 'ptr1' after the internal while loop is finished. Otherwise, the first node will be compared with the second node and then the first node will be modified to the next node. So the first node will not get compared with other nodes.