# Singly Linked List, insert at end

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Due to reasons beyond my control, the function declaration must not change. I'm not very good with pointers, so the NODE** declaration really throws me off.

I know the basic gist is more or less correct. I just keep getting errors due to the pointers and don't know how to solve it.

There is currently an error in this line of the else statement:

```
NODE* last = data;

//a value of type "NODE **" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "NODE *"
```

Yet I don't know if I've been handling the pointers correctly.

```
class NODE {
  public:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    string email;
    NODE* next;
};

void add_node_tail(NODE** data, string firstname,string lastname, string email) {
    NODE* temp = new NODE;
    temp->firstname = firstname;
    temp->lastname = lastname;
    temp->email = email;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(!data) { // empty list becomes the new node
        data = &temp;
        return;
    } else { // find last and link the new node
        NODE* last = data;
        while(last->next) {
            last=last->next;
            last->next = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you could give me a rundown of how the pointers would work in the correct implementation, that would be the perfect answer.

Comment: "Due to reasons out of my control" = "This is a school assignment", isn't it? Please be sure to check whether your school's policy allows you to ask questions about homework.

Comment: Do you have an example of how `add_node_tail` is called, and why it is called that way?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov I did check! There is no mention about any rules on asking questions. So why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NODE** data` is a pointer to `NODE*`, so you should dereference the pointer like `*data` to get the value of `NODE*`.

```
void add_node_tail(NODE** data, string firstname,string lastname, string email) {
    NODE* temp = new NODE;
    temp->firstname = firstname;
    temp->lastname = lastname;
    temp->email = email;
    temp->next = NULL;

    // *** dereference data to get the value ***
    if(!*data) { // empty list becomes the new node
        // *** dereference data to set the value ***
        // also remove the extra & not to save a pointer to local variable
        *data = temp;
        return;
    } else { // find last and link the new node
        // *** dereference data to get the value ***
        NODE* last = *data;
        while(last->next) {
            last=last->next;
            last->next = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there is a neat trick you can use to skip the first test and reduce the amount of code needed. The [**Community Addition** here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) shows how to remove a node using a pointer to a pointer, but the insertion logic is similar.

Comment: Thank you! Your comments really helped!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way to look at the problem.

`data` is (or better be because the asker's code and all of the answers won't work if it is not) pointer to a next pointer. The head pointer is a next pointer by another name; think of it as the first next pointer. There's nothing special about it, so if you abstract away the different name by taking a pointer to it, you can write much simpler code. `data` has already done this first step.

This means all you need to do is find the first null next pointer and point it at the new node.

```cpp
void add_node_tail(NODE** data, string firstname,string lastname, string email) {
    while (*data) { // if data points at a non-null next
        data = &(*data)->next; // point at the pointer to the next node
    }
    *data = new NODE{ firstname, lastname, email, NULL }; // insert at last next
}
```

Note:  `new NODE{ firstname, lastname, email, NULL };` is making use of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to make the initialization easier to write.