# Will there be a memory leak in this Linked list

Tags: c++

Hi Currently i have been honing my skill in the data structure so that i can become a good Game Developer, i am Learning Linked list and made a Linked list Program with Insertion ,Deletion and Recursive insertion and Reversing a Linked list Can you Guys tell me am i here Clearing the assigned memory Created with the new Operator Correctly, I am getting the Desired Output but i am worried about memory leak. ... please be gentle aim Still learning.

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node *Next;

public:
    int GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    void SetData(int Data)
    {
        data = Data;
    }

    Node *GetNext()
    {
        return Next;
    }

    void SetNext(Node *next)
    {
        Next = next;
    }
};

void Insert(Node **Head, int x)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();

    temp->SetData(x);
    temp->SetNext(*Head);

    *Head = temp;
}

void InsertAt(Node **Head, int x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "The Given data at 'n' cannot be assigned to null\n";
    }

    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->SetData(x);
    if (n == 1)
    {
        temp->SetNext(nullptr);
        *Head = temp;
        return;
    }

    Node *temp2 = *Head;
    if (Head == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "The Given data cannot be assigned to null\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->GetNext();
    }

    temp->SetNext(temp2->GetNext());
    temp2->SetNext(temp);
}

void AppendList(Node **Head, int Data)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();

    Node *LastNode = *Head;

    temp->SetData(Data);
    temp->SetNext(nullptr);

    if (*Head == nullptr)
    {
        *Head = temp;
        return;
    }
    // else Traverse till last node.

    while (LastNode->GetNext() != nullptr)
    {
        LastNode = LastNode->GetNext();
    }
    LastNode->SetNext(temp);
}

void DeleteNode(Node **Head, int n)
{
    Node *temp = *Head;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        *Head = temp->GetNext();
        std::cout << "\nAfter Deletion of Head Node\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
    {
        temp = temp->GetNext();
    }
    Node *temp2 = temp->GetNext();
    temp->SetNext(temp2->GetNext());
    std::cout << "After Deletion of Node\n";
}

Node *ReverseList(Node *Head)
{
    Node *Current, *Prev, *next;

    Current = Head;
    Prev = nullptr;
    while (Current != nullptr)
    {
        next = Current->GetNext();
        Current->SetNext(Prev);
        Prev = Current;
        Current = next;
    }
    Head = Prev;
    return Head;
}

int LinkedList_Count(Node *Head)
{
    int count = 0;

    Node *Current = Head;
    while (Current != nullptr)
    {
        count++;
        Current = Current->GetNext();
    }
    std::cout << "Number of Elements: " << count;
    return count;
}

void PrintList(Node *Head)
{
    std::cout << "Data list : ";

    while (Head != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << " " << Head->GetData();
        Head = Head->GetNext();
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

//Print Listed using Recursion
void Recursion_Print(Node *Head)
{
    if (Head == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << ' ' << Head->GetData(); //comment to Do Reverse the Linked list
    Recursion_Print(Head->GetNext());
    //std::cout << ' ' << Head->GetData();//unComment to Reverse the linked List recursively
}

Node *RecursiveRevList(Node *Head)
{
    Node *temp;
    if (Head->GetNext() == nullptr)
    {
        temp = Head;
        return temp;
    }
    temp = RecursiveRevList(Head->GetNext());
    Head->GetNext()->SetNext(Head);
    Head->SetNext(nullptr);
    return temp;
}
void RunList()
{
    Node *Head = NULL;

    //AppendList(&Head, 16);
    Insert(&Head, 6);
    Insert(&Head, 7);
    Insert(&Head, 8);
    InsertAt(&Head, 18, 2);
    std::cout << "Data list : \n";
    Recursion_Print(Head);
    std::cout << '\n';
    LinkedList_Count(Head);
    DeleteNode(&Head, 1);
    //Head = ReverseList(Head);
    Head = RecursiveRevList(Head);
    PrintList(Head);
    LinkedList_Count(Head);
    delete Head;
}
```

Comment: You certainly have a leak, since you never free memory, nor do you use a smart pointer that will free memory automatically.  In particular your `DeleteNode` detaches a node from the list but never deletes it.

Comment: The best way to check if there are no memory leaks is to write extensive tests and run them under leak-detecting tool like valgrind. It's hard to detect memory leaks just by looking at code, especially if it's not conforming to RAII principle.

Comment: Where does DeleteNode free the node that is removed?

Comment: Unrelated and more of a personal reflection, but the resource or teacher you use to learn C++ might be doing a bad job of teaching C++. You clearly know about classes, so why don't you use classes for the list itself? Making all the global functions member functions of e.g. a `List` class?

Comment: Linked list is one of the few places I would use `new`, particularly if I knew the list will be long enough to threaten stack overflow. In this case there's already recursive iteration, so might as well use the `unique_ptr`. In general Here's an excellent presentation on C++'s smart pointers: [Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE) If I'm not mixing up presentation, sI beleve this is the one where Mr. Sutter uses linked list as an example.

Comment: [Related: The **Community addition** in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) demonstrates a way to use an extra layer of indirection to dramatically simplify the book-keeping required when modifying, in this case removing a node, a linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing C-style code; in C++, you should [avoid explicit calls to `new`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete).  Your example is [far too long to rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but here is a very small start:

```
#include <memory>
class Node
{
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> Next;

// ...
void Insert(std::shared_ptr<Node>& Head, int x)
{
    auto temp = std::make_shared<Node>();
    // ...
}
```

(Note that `std::unique_ptr` is probably a better choice than `std::shared_ptr`, but that incurs complications with copying `Node` of which you're "blissfully" unaware right now.)

And, in practice, you should really use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (in your case, `std::list<int>`) rather than writing your own. Once you're proficient *using* `std::list` (and friends like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)), you'll be better able to "roll your own."

Comment: @TricksterRazor Ðаn's point is valid, though. It boils down to *manual memory management is NOT basic.* It is an intermediate-to-advanced level skill, and one of the harder things to get right in programming. Even for the experts, so do what the experts do: Use it extremely rarely.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments by many learned people, you *have a memory leak in your program*. When you are deleting the nodes, you're not actually freeing the allocated memory locations. The correct way? Use `delete` to deallocate the memory from the program.

I would recommend you to learn it as a rule of thumb, when programming in C or C++, if you're allocating dynamic memory somewhere in your program, then in all certainty you'd have some deletion method where you should use `free()` or `delete` to deallocate the memory from the heap.

Here are some resources which might help you.

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-30/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-in-c/
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete (might be a little hard if you're a beginner)

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)