# LinkedList Remove function fails when deleting from the end of the list C++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list, member-functions

I have a LinkedList class and everything works except for my remove function. It works except for when it is removing from the end. If I remove from the end and then try to display the new list the program crashes and doesnt give me an error. I was wondering if someone could help me pinpoint what I did wrong in the remove function where I am removing the tail.

Main method

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void MainMenu(int& menu);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int menu = 0;
    string name;
    LinkedList list;
    while (true)
    {
        
        MainMenu(menu);
        if (menu == 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name you want to add to the front: " << endl;
            cin >> name;
            list.addFront(name);
        }
        else if (menu == 2)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name you want to add to the back: " << endl;
            cin >> name;
            list.addBack(name);
        }
        else if (menu == 3)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name you want to remove: " << endl;
            cin >> name;
            list.remove(name);
        }
        else if (menu == 4)
        {
            list.display();
        }
        else if (menu == 5)
        {
            cout << "\nThank you for using my program!" << endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
void MainMenu(int& menu)
{
    cout << '\n' << endl;
    cout << left << setw(30) << right << setw(20) << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << setw(36) << setfill('*') << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add node to front." << endl;
    cout << "2. Add node to back." << endl;
    cout << "3. Remove node." << endl;
    cout << "4. Display list." << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit" << endl;
    cout << setw(36) << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a menu number to proceed: " << endl;
    cin >> menu;
    while (menu != 1 && menu != 2 && menu != 3 && menu != 4 && menu != 5)
    {
        cout << "Menu options are 1 - 5" << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a menu number to proceed: " << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> menu;
    }
    cout << setfill(' ') << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Header file

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
struct Node
{
    string name;
    Node * next;
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node * head = nullptr;
    Node * tail = nullptr;
    Node * current = nullptr;
    void addFront(string name);
    void addBack(string name);
    void remove(string name);
    void display();
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& orig);
    virtual ~LinkedList();
private:

};

#endif /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

Source File

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

void LinkedList::addFront(string name)
{
    Node * node = new Node();
    node->name = name;
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    }
}
void LinkedList::addBack(string name)
{
    Node * node = new Node();
    node->name = name;
    node->next = nullptr;
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
      
        node->next = nullptr;
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
    }
}

void LinkedList::remove(string name)
{
    Node * temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->name == name)
        {
            cout << "Name found! Being removed." << endl;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
        if (temp == nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Name not found!" << endl;
            return;
        }
    } 
    temp = head;
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty." << endl;
        return;
    }
    while(!(temp->name == name))
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp == tail && temp == head)
    {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        delete temp;
    }
    else if (temp == tail)
    {
        temp->next = tail;
        delete temp->next;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else if(temp == head)
    {
        temp = head;
        head = temp->next;
 
        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while(!(temp->next->name == name))
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        Node * next = temp->next->next;
        delete temp->next;
        temp->next = next;  
        
    }
    
}
void LinkedList::display()
{
    current = head;
    if (current == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty!" << endl;
    }
    while (current != nullptr)
    {
        cout << current->name << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
LinkedList::LinkedList() {
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& orig) {
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
}
```

Comment: yeah, your code for `if (temp == tail)` doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: thats not the problem

Comment: else if (temp == tail)
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp->next;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    tail = temp;
    }

Comment: you should start over and rewrite your remove method. You only need one loop. Track the `current` and `previous` nodes. When you find a match, remove it and then do the checks for head and tail. If `previous` is null, it means it is the head.

Comment: it is the problem. You said it doesn't work for removing the last item, and in that case it will execute the `temp == tail` code, which uses a deleted pointer for one thing

Comment: this code works to remove it if i put it in my if statement...i just was trying to do it without cycling through``` else if (temp == tail)
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp->next->next != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp->next;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    tail = temp;
    }

Comment: I dont know how to do that with one loop, because when you find your match if its in the middle your still going to have to cycle through again to get to the one before it.

Comment: This is for a class and we dont have a previous so I cant use that

Comment: You should simplify your `main` function for this question's [mre] (not for your homework assignment, just for this Stack Overflow question). Drop the menu. The only things the `main` function needs to do is reproduce your error with a minimum of code (and preferably no user input). That is, define a `LinkedList` variable, add two nodes, remove the last one, then display the results. Short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is this section here

```
else if (temp == tail)
    {
        temp->next = tail;
        delete temp->next;
        temp->next = nullptr;
        tail = temp;
    }
```

That is what executes if the match is the last item. But if it is the last item then `temp->next` will be `tail` because you just set it to tail, and since `temp == tail` that also invalidates `temp`.  Setting `temp->next` will be using a deleted pointer. There's no fixing this at this point because you need the previous node to set tail to, and you didn't save it, so you'd have to loop through again to get it.

Now, for the solution, you should do a single loop. No need to loop multiple times (3 in most cases)

```
void LinkedList::remove(string name)
{
    Node * temp = head;
    Node * prev = nullptr;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->name == name)
        {
            cout << "Name found! Being removed." << endl;
            if (prev != nullptr) {
                prev->next = temp->next
            }
            else {
                head = temp->next;
            }
            if (tail == temp) {
                tail = prev;
            }
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    } 
    cout << "Name not found!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: note this will only remove the first occurance of `name`, but could be modified to remove all of them

Comment: dang that works...now i have to figure out how you did that

Comment: man i would never have figured that out...i had to do it by trial and error

Comment: the only question i have is in your solution we are not setting the next to nullptr in some of the cases like if we are deleting the tail and moving it back or if there is just one node and we delete it...is that a big deal?

Comment: nevermind i see how it is getting set thanks

Comment: Side note: The community addition in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) demonstrates an approach using a pointer-to-pointer that greatly simplifies node removal by abstracting away notions like `head` and combining `temp` and `prev` into the same variable.

Comment: @user4581301 That version doesn't maintain a `tail` pointer. The `tail` isn't really necessary but can make appending to the list O(1) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

For starters everywhere in member function declarations where a parameter is declared like

```
string name
```

you should change it to

```
const string &name
```

Secondly the member function `remove` shall not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output a message.

Your function is inefficient because it traverses the list two or even three times in loops and has too many conditions that makes the function too complicated. As a result the function has bugs.

For example in this if statement

```
else if (temp == tail)
{
    temp->next = tail;
    delete temp->next;
    temp->next = nullptr;
    tail = temp;
}
```

there is used deleted pointer `temp` to access memory because `temp` is equal to `tail` (according to the condition of the if statement)

```
    temp->next = nullptr;
```

and tail again is set to the deleted pointer

```
    tail = temp;
```

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    //...
    bool remove( const std::string &name );
};

bool LinkedList::remove( const std::string &name )
{
    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node *current = head;
    
    while ( current && current->name != name )
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    bool success = current != nullptr;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        if ( prev )
        {
            prev->next = current->next;
            if ( prev->next == nullptr ) tail = prev;
        }
        else
        {
            head = head->next;
            if ( head == nullptr ) tail = nullptr;
        }
        
        delete current;
    }
    
    return success;
}
```