# Cannot Insert Item into Linked List

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
void LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos) {
  Node *newNode = new Node;
  newNode->data = num;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  if(pos == 0) {
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
  else {
    Node *temp = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < pos-1; ++i) {
      if (temp != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
      }
    }
    if (temp != NULL) {
      newNode->next = temp->next;
      temp->next = newNode;
    }
    else {
      cout << " The previous node is full.";
    }
  }
}
```

This is my insert function.
The code that runs in main.cpp is:

```
// adding through insert
    nums.insert(1, 0);
    nums.insert(5, 4);
    nums.insert(3, 7);
```

And the output is:

```
List after append: 
8   6   7   8   0   9

List after inserting: 
1   8   6   5   7   8
```

As you can see, something is getting overwritten, or the end of the list just gets cut off. I have searched the internet for hours to no avail. The output needs to increase the length of the list and not overwrite anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show how the output code looks like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xg9sWbJ5

Comment: The exact code as shown, running *only* what is demonstrated in your 'main.cpp', should produce two declarations of "The previous node is full." and a single node '1' in the list printout. So, how about we update this question with a proper [mcve] that actually produces the output you're claiming.

Comment: @dman773 What does this message cout << " The previous node is full."; mean?! I think that if the position exceeds the size of the list then a new node should be appended to the end of the list.

Comment: Adding an item to a singly linked list is ludicrously easy if you abstract away the difference between `head` and `next` with a pointer to a pointer. [Here's a trick from WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) showing how to remove an item from a list that you can steal ideas from.

Comment: @user4581301 lols. I remember updating that :-) Anyway for the OP, that same nuance adapted to the OPs code [is here](https://pastebin.com/q2mekUaV), including the odd announcement of "full" (whatever that means) on positional overreach.

Comment: @dman773 The code shown does not produce the output shown ([demo](https://ideone.com/aSOunC)). The output I get is: `List after inserting: 1 8 6 5 7 8 3 0 9`, which is still not correct, but is not what you claim. The output is `1 8 6 7 5 8 0 3 9` after fixing the broken loop in `insert()` as [Vlad suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71961294/65863) ([demo](https://ideone.com/BuIsLx)), or as WhozCraig suggested ([demo](https://ideone.com/WUL0V9)).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < pos-1; ++i) {
  if (temp != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}
```

Let's assume that `pos` is equal to `2`. In this case the loop will not iterate and `temp` will be equal to `head`. So the new node will be inserted before the second mode instead to be inserted before the third node.

You need to write

```
for (int i = 1; temp != nullptr && i < pos; ++i) {
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Also instead of writing this message

```
 cout << " The previous node is full.";
```

(it is the caller of the function should decide whether to output a message) I would declare the function like

```
bool LinkedList::insert(int num, int pos) {
```

and return either true or false dependent on whether a node was inserted.