# Trying to create a singly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am new to C++ and only know Java.

I am trying to create a singly linked list in C++ that will allow me to store integer numbers within the nodes. I want also to have the `IntNode` class and `IntLinkedList` class in separate files from the main file.

However, it's not working, I think it has something to do with my `add()` method for my `IntLinkedList` class.

This is the `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntNode.hpp"
#include "IntLinkedList.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //Initializing Variables
    IntLinkedList myList;
    
    myList.add(5);
    
    std::cout << "-------Done.------";
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the `IntNode.cpp` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "IntNode.hpp"

IntNode::IntNode(int newData, IntNode *newLink)
{
    data = newData;
    link = newLink;
}

int IntNode::getData()
{
    return data;
}

IntNode IntNode::getLink()
{
    return *link;
}

void IntNode::setData(int newData)
{
    data = newData;
}
void IntNode::setLink(IntNode *newLink)
{
    link = newLink;
}
```

This is the `IntNode.hpp` header file:

```
#ifndef IntNode_h
#define IntNode_h

class IntNode
{
private:
    int data;
    IntNode *link;
public:
    IntNode(int newData, IntNode *newLink);
    int getData();
    IntNode getLink();
    void setData(int newData);
    void setLink(IntNode *newLink);
};

#endif /* IntNode_h */
```

This is the `IntLinkedList.cpp` file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "IntLinkedList.hpp"
#include "IntNode.hpp"

IntLinkedList::IntLinkedList()
{
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    numElements = 0;
}

void IntLinkedList::add(int newElement)
{
    if(!(tail))
    {
        *head = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        *tail = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);
        tail->getLink() = *tail;
    }
    numElements++;
}
```

This is the `IntLinkedList.hpp` header file:

```
#ifndef IntLinkedList_hpp
#define IntLinkedList_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "IntNode.hpp"

class IntLinkedList
{
private:
    IntNode *head;
    IntNode *tail;
    int numElements;
public:
    IntLinkedList();
    void add(int newElement);
};

#endif /* IntLinkedList_hpp */
```

When I run the code, it gave me this:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

and highlights this piece of code, which is part of the `IntLinkedList::add()` method:

```
*head = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);
```

Comment: Do you know what dynamic scoping is, in C++, and how to use it? Do you thoroughly understand what pointers are, in C++, how they work, and how to use them? Your constructor sets `headptr` to `nullptr`. Afterwards `add()` sets `*head = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);`. With `head` being a `nullptr`, what did you expect to happen here?

Comment: `*head = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);` -- You are dereferencing a null pointer `head`.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173)

Comment: `int *p = nullptr; *p = 10;` -- That essentially is what your code is doing.  Do you see the issue with that simple example?

Comment: Java got `new`. In C++ pointers are close to what in java are variables but you have control over the  stored address.

Comment: Unrelated: Do what you can to hide the exitance of `IntNode` from the user. The more the user knows about the inner workings of a class, the more they will take advantage of and the  more brittle their code will be should you have to change that class.

Comment: Since you have not gotten far enough in your list implementation to use any of the data in `IntNode`, you could -- for this question -- reduce that definition down to `class IntNode { /* placeholder */ };` and stick this definition inside `IntLinkedList.hpp` (between `#define IntLinkedList_hpp` and `class IntLinkedList` -- none of the headers should be needed after this change). Removing unnecessary code and getting people to the problematic code faster is a Good Thing for SO questions.

Comment: *"I want also to have the `IntNode` class and `IntLinkedList` class in separate files from the main file."* -- This is a good goal for your program. However, for your question, it would be beneficial to combine everything into a single code block, in case someone wants to copy-compile-run your code to reproduce your result. A single code block means only a single copy-paste for the person *volunteering* to help. (Work in a new project or an online compiler so that refining your minimal example does not disrupt your real project.)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost - C++ already has a native single-linked list class: [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). And a native double-linked list class: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).  You really should use these classes instead of creating your own.

That being said, if you must create your own classes (ie, for a school assignment), then know that your classes are not using pointers correctly:

- in `IntNode::getLink()`, you are dereferencing the `link` pointer when it should be returned as-is.  This will fail if `getLink()` is called on the `tail` node of `IntLinkedList` since `link` will be `nullptr` in that case.
- in `IntLinkedList::add()`, you are dereferencing the `head` pointer when it is `nullptr`, which is why you get the runtime error.
- in `IntLinkedList::add()`, you are also using `getLink()` incorrectly.  You are assigning a new `IntNode` object to the current `tail` object, thus changing its `data` and `link`. And then you are calling `getLink()` on the current `tail` object, which will fail for the reason mentioned further above - its `link` is `nullptr`.  You should be linking the new `IntNode` object to the current `tail` object, not replacing the current `tail` object.

You need to dynamically allocate the `IntNode` objects via the [`new` expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) (just like in Java), otherwise the objects will get destroyed as soon as they go out of scope.

You also need to implement the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) in the `IntLinkedList` class to manage the `IntNode` objects correctly when an `IntLinkedList` object is copied, moved, assigned to, destroyed, etc.

Your code should look more like the following:

`IntNode.hpp`:

```
#ifndef IntNode_hpp
#define IntNode_hpp

class IntNode
{
private:
    int data;
    IntNode *link;
public:
    IntNode(int newData, IntNode *newLink = nullptr);
    int getData();
    IntNode* getLink();
    void setData(int newData);
    void setLink(IntNode *newLink);
};

#endif /* IntNode_hpp */
```

`IntNode.cpp`:

```
#include "IntNode.hpp"

IntNode::IntNode(int newData, IntNode *newLink)
    : data(newData), link(newLink)
{
}

int IntNode::getData()
{
    return data;
}

IntNode* IntNode::getLink()
{
    return link;
}

void IntNode::setData(int newData)
{
    data = newData;
}

void IntNode::setLink(IntNode *newLink)
{
    link = newLink;
}
```

`IntLinkedList.hpp`:

```
#ifndef IntLinkedList_hpp
#define IntLinkedList_hpp

#include "IntNode.hpp"

class IntLinkedList
{
private:
    IntNode *head = nullptr;
    IntNode *tail = nullptr;
    int numElements = 0;
public:
    IntLinkedList() = default;
    IntLinkedList(const IntLinkedList &src);
    IntLinkedList(IntLinkedList &&src);
    ~IntLinkedList();

    IntLinkedList& operator=(IntLinkedList src);

    void add(int newElement);
};

#endif /* IntLinkedList_hpp */
```

`IntLinkedList.cpp`:

```
#include "IntLinkedList.hpp"
#include <utility>

IntLinkedList::IntLinkedList(const IntLinkedList &src)
    : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), numElements(0)
{
    IntNode *node = src.head;
    while (node)
    {
        add(node->getData());
        node = node->getLink();
    }
}

IntLinkedList::IntLinkedList(IntLinkedList &&src)
    : head(src.head), tail(src.tail), numElements(src.numElements)
{
    src.head = nullptr;
    src.tail = nullptr;
    src.numElements = 0;
}

IntLinkedList::~IntLinkedList()
{
    IntNode *node = head;
    while (node)
    {
        IntNode *link = node->getLink();
        delete node;
        node = link;
    }
}

IntLinkedList& IntLinkedList::operator=(IntLinkedList src)
{
    std::swap(head, src.head);
    std::swap(tail, src.tail);
    std::swap(numElements, src.numElements);
    return *this;
}

void IntLinkedList::add(int newElement)
{
    IntNode *node = new IntNode(newElement);
    if (!head)
    {
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->setLink(node);
    }
    tail = node;
    ++numElements;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Sooner or later you'll be tasked with removing an item from the list. [See the Community Addition in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) for a simple and efficient way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

> `*head = IntNode(newElement, nullptr);`

This says to create a (temporary) `IntNode` object, then copy that object to the object to which `head` points. However, the only value that has been assigned to `head` is `nullptr`, so there is no object to which `head` points. Copying to a non-existent object is a valid reason for crashing.

What you want is to create a new `IntNode` object (not a temporary), then have `head` point to that object. Change `head` not `*head`.

```cpp
head = new IntNode(newElement, nullptr);
```

Don't forget to `delete` the object later. This means having a destructor, which leads to [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722).

*Note:* This is not the only bug in your code, just the one currently showing symptoms. I'll leave the rest for other questions or answers.