# Why is Linked list not considered a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make a template LinkedList class, but when I try to compile, I get this error "LinkedList.cpp:11:7: error: 'LinkedList' is not a template". I think it might have something to do with Node.cpp adding LinkedList as a friend class, but I am new to c++, so I don't know, and if it is something to do with the friend class, I do not know how to fix it.

I wanted to make a linkedList class, but I ran into an error with templates. I ran into this problem on an earlier project, and it bested me, so I gave up. I tried messing with the multiple inclusion defense, changing where my code was(template header file code in the normal file, ect.) , and I tried using chat gpt to no avail.

I don't know for sure what the issue is, so I have given all 4 of my files they are LinkedList.cpp, LinkedList.h, Node.cpp, and test.cpp. LinkedList.cpp, LinkedList.h, and Node.cpp make up the LinkedList, and test.cpp is where I run my program to test the LinkedList.

LinkedList.cpp

```
//t LinkedList.cpp
//--linking
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//--consrs.
template<typename E>
LinkedList<E>::LinkedList(){
    head = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}
```

LinkedList.h

```
//t LinkedList.h
//--include deff.
#ifndef LinkedList_h
#define LinkedList_h

//--linking
#include "Node.cpp"

//--class
template<typename E>
class LinkedList{
public:

    //--consrs.
    LinkedList();
};

#endif
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
//t Node.cpp
//--class
template<typename E>
class Node{
public:
    friend class LinkedList<E>;
};
```

test.cpp

```
//t test.cpp
//--linking
#include "LinkedList.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//--main
int main(){
    LinkedList<int> myList;
}
```

Note: I am new to stack overflow, so my apologies if I did not explain something right.

Comment: `LinkedList.cpp:11` doesn't match your code. Please post a real [mcve] and actual compete errors in a code block (a pre-formatted text).

Comment: `#include "Node.cpp" #include "LinkedList.cpp"` this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Linked list includes node. Node includes linked list. This usually ends badly. Could be the bug as well. At the point `friend class LinkedList<E>;` is going to appear in to the compiler, `LinkedList` isn't a template. It hasn't been defined at all.

Comment: LinkedList.cpp:7 still doesn't match the code. That line is `//--consrs.`

Comment: So `LinkedList.h` defines `LinkedList_h`, then includes `Node.cpp`. `Node.cpp` includes `LinkedList.h` right back, but this time `LinkedList_h` macro is already defined, so the whole header is skipped. Then `Node.cpp` tries to use the name `LinkedList` - but it hasn't been declared yet, as a template or otherwise. You may wish to read about forward declarations in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Many tools will see the .cpp extension and build the cpp file just like it is supposed to. But when you include a file, a copy of the included file is pasted into the including file. Now you have two coppies of everything in the .cpp file and the linker won't know which one is real.

Comment: Here is what the compiler sees: https://godbolt.org/z/Pn368azv4

Comment: Side note: In a good linked list, the linked list class hides the node class as a `private` member. This helps keep outsiders from messing with the linked list's nodes. In this case it also makes most of your problems go away: https://godbolt.org/z/3TnEzGvvK

Comment: And once you hide the `Node`, there is no point to it having any access restrictions because ONLY `LinkedList` can work with it. No need for `friend`ship, so the code gets even simpler: https://godbolt.org/z/rfnxxo3Wa

Comment: And filling in a few more blanks, you get a nice, simple starting point: https://godbolt.org/z/of7nMdKsP

Comment: This next bit is really <expletive deleted>ing important: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/4581301) This is why it feels like you have to shoot yourself in the foot by including the .cpp files. The solution is to not use the .cpp extension. Use another header. Maybe call it LinkedList.hpp. Or build the whole class into one header. Both work. I prefer the latter. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/7EP6Wjs6r

Comment: Future note: Eventually you'll have to remove items from the linked list. Check out the pointer-to-pointer trick used in the [Community Addition to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301). Probably save you a few days of debugging.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. Y'all have been a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for the node template is in the source (.cpp) file.  Template definitions should be in the header file.

See the following: [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: Not the asker's issue. They side-stepped this problem by including the cpp files, also good source of bad, and shot themselves in the foot with a cycle in the includes.